# Java stream foreach parameter ask user for value

Tags: java, system.in

I am building a cli utility in which I must ask for input from the user from a dynamically generated set of parameters. To accomplish this we have a list of Strings and we create a HashMap of (key value pairs of parameter name and the value provided from the cli input).

Here is a working sample:

```
public class ConfigBuilderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("parameterOne");
        list.add("parameterTwo");
        list.add("parameterThree");
        promptForParameterInput(list);
    }


    public static HashMap<String, String> promptForParameterInput(List<String> parameters) {
        System.out.println("There are " + parameters.size() + " parameters to designate.");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.forEach(parameter -> {
            System.out.println("provide a value for " + parameter + ": ");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String input = null;
            try {
                input = bufferedReader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            map.put(parameter, input);
        });
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;
    }


}
```

now - when I run the application it prompts me for parameterOne and I input a value, but when I press return it does not force the application forward - I must press return a second time. Then all the other parameters seem to function correctly: I am asked at the cli for a parameter value, I provide the value, and it moves on to the next parameter.

Here's a sample of the cli output:

```
There are 3 parameters to designate.
provide a value for parameterOne: 
test

provide a value for parameterTwo: 
value
provide a value for parameterThree: 
provided
{parameterOne=, parameterThree=provided, parameterTwo=value}
```

I have spent too much time on this simple problem already - hoping someone has run across this before and knows the answer :)

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Copy pasted and ran your code, it seems to be working as expected

Comment: maybe it's an intelliJ RUN issue? - you are running from CLI directly?

Comment: Working fine no issue with code I think its different beh of your CLI try in another CLI or try on some online compiler.

Comment: thanks - working from cli directly - some issue with IntelliJ IDE run command...

Comment: @Jeff ran from both command line and IntelliJ, works fine in both cases

Comment: @Bentaye I'm on intelliJ 2019.1.1 ... time to finally update this I guess lol